# Why don't these abstract methods need to be implemented?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

What am I missing here?  In the following webpage, it's explained how to write a SOAP extension class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188761.aspx

In the proposed extension class, which begins:

> ```
> public class XmlStreamSoapExtension : SoapExtension
> ```

... only `ChainStream` and `ProcessMessage` are implemented.  However, if I do something similar and try to build, I get build errors that 3 abstract methods:

> ```
> GetInitializer(Type serviceType)  
> GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
> Initialize(object initializer)
> ```

... have not been implemented.  Have they just been omitted for brevity, or am I missing something here that allows you not to have to implement them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you notice in the example code, the line

```
  ... // no-op operations omitted for simplicity
```

says that they have intentionally omitted these methods (for simplicity).

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  I think it's a bit lazy for them to have done that, though; they're one-liners, and they're not exactly no-ops either because two of them require something to be returned.  Ah well.

Answer (score 5):

As stated on the page you link:

> I omitted a couple of no-op operations for simplicity.